# Workflow.xaml - Copy to SharePoint root

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2012

When I'm writing Assemblies, I can copy to GAC and avoid re-deploying them each time I want to make a code change.
When I'm writing ASPX forms, I can copy them to SharePoint root, maybe give an IIS reset and I'm done.
With workflows, I'm forced to go through the whole process. I've tried copying to SharePoint root, writing a script to replace the Workflow.xaml file, restarting the "Workflow Manager Backend" and all other SharePoint services.

It just doesn't work. Every time I make a change to my SharePoint 2013, visual studio workflow, I'm forced to redeploy the solution and re-attach the workflow to it's respective list. This takes less than 5 minutes, but imagine having to do that each time you have a minor change?

Is there a way of speeding up the debugging process?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following command mentioned in the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286924/sharepoint-2013-visual-studio-workflow-not-updating

So you don't have to attach the workflow again. But you have to deploy the solution again.

Comment: You serious? That's my own answer...

Comment: Sorry for this. But i was facing the same issue some days back. And this link helped me. I was not aware that its your answer.